# Group By Is Being Translated Locally? How to Fix this?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-core

I am seeing this "warning" in my logs. I am using EF Core 2.2.4

> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType95`2(Date = [x].CreatedDate.Date, EmployeeId = [x].EmployeeId), [x])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

my query looks like this

```
var groupedEvents = dbContext.EventTrackings
    .Where(x => // where clause )
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.CreatedDate.Date, x.EmployeeId })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Date)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If you remove the `Date` do you still get the warning? I mean use just `x.CreatedDate`

Comment: Probably because of `x.CreatedDate.Date`, which generates a short date out of your date. Try without that function or add another (computed) column to the table that hold the ShortDate value.

Comment: I thought that may be the reason, so I removed CreatedDate completely but still see it.The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType95`1(EmployeeId = [x].EmployeeId), [x])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Comment: @chobo2 avoid the use of `new` inside group by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102821/translating-query-with-group-by-and-count-to-linq now your warning should not be there

Comment: how would I do the multiple grouping then? Also I did try remvoing the new and still seeing it. The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([x].EmployeeId, [x])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: @chobo2 you are coreect you need this. I will do some testing. In the meantime does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807038/ef-core-group-by-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally

Comment: It is weird that I am getting it with anything in that groupBy event he most simple one. I would try 3.0 but I would have to go to core 3.0 I guess and don't really want to take that big of a task on.

Comment: @chobo2 Where is your select query ?

Comment: @chobo2 All you'll get if you go to EF Core 3.0+ is runtime exception instead of warning. The problem is not the key, but the whole LINQ `GroupBy` w/o select of key/aggregates, which has no SQL equivalent. For more info, see EF Core docs - [Complex Query Operations - Group By](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating named property in your anonymous type `.GroupBy(x => new { CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate.Date, x.EmployeeId })`. I think it's not able to find and convert the `Date` property name to DB table column name if your actual db column name is `CreatedDate`.

```
var groupedEvents = dbContext.EventTrackings
    .Where(x => // where clause )
    .GroupBy(x => new { CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate.Date, x.EmployeeId })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.CreatedDate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: So you suggesting to make a concrete type? The weird thing is I tried something simple like " .GroupBy(x =>  x.EmployeeId )" but I getting the same "warning"

Comment: `x.Created.Date` will generate property name `Date` on anonymous type so it's just a named property it's still antonymous type. Added a sample for clarification.

Comment: Still getting the same thing: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType95`2(CreatedDate = [x].CreatedDate.Date, EmployeeId = [x].EmployeeId), [x])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: Can you try removing your `OrderBy()`?

Comment: Yea I removed it awhile back and same thing.

Comment: hmmm.. I can't find any [tests on EFCore 2.2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Specification.Tests/Query/GroupByQueryTestBase.cs) supporting the grouping by anonymous type for multiple fields. May be it's not supported in this version.

Comment: Only thing I found was: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1

Comment: The one thing, I see is that they use "Select" which seems to be the key to get rid of the error, I am playing around it right now. Kinda sucks though as that means you going to have to write all properties you want in the select.

Comment: Sadly even in EFCore 3.0 instead of fixing the actual issue.. I found this [issue/request](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14935) from MS team suggesting disabling such warnings.

Comment: hmm so it is planned but nothing in the work. I wonder what the performance hit is right now. with using GroupBy as I been using it vs going through the effort of doing the select to make the error go away.